# Kohana 3.2. table name not found

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3

I'm using kohana 3.2. and I'm having some trouble getting this new model to work..
There's the model: `Model_User_Unavailability` which works fine and there's the model `Model_User_Unavailability_Status` which doesn't.

The problem isn't finding the model, it's using it. I can make a status using: `ORM::factory('user_unavailability_status');` and it works just fine, but when I want to add the status to the unavailability class it won't work and I'm getting the following exception:

```
Incorrect table name '' [ INSERT INTO `` (`user_unavailability_id`, `status_id`) VALUES ('670', NULL) ]
```

The classes look like this:

```
class Model_User_Unavailability extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'user' => array(),
    );
    protected $_table_name = 'user_unavailability';

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'status' => array(
            'model' => 'User_Unavailability_Status', 
            'foreign_key' => 'user_unavailability_id'
        )
    );
...etc
```

­

```
class Model_User_Unavailability_Status extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'user_unavailability_status';
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'user_unavailability' => array(
            'foreign_key' => 'user_unavailability_id', 
            'model' => 'user_unavailability'
        )
    );
    etc...
```

Now the exception appears when I try the following:

```
$db = $user->unavailable->where('id', '=', $id)->find(); // Returns User_Unavailability object
//... do some other stuf...
$db->save();

if($db->loaded())
{
    $status = ORM::factory('user_unavailability_status');
    $status->status = 'requested';
    $status->responder_id = 1;
    $db->add('status',$status);
}
```

As you can see in the exception earlier it won't use the specified table name. However, when I remove the $_table_name variable from the status class I get the following error:

```
Table 'urenregistratie.user_unavailability_statuses' doesn't exist [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user_unavailability_statuses` ]
```

As you can see it does find the model, but won't find the database table. So my question here is, what's going on here? I guess I'm missing something but I don't know what...

Same happens when i use the `$this->_table_names_plural = false` in the status model.

So... any suggestions / ideas?

**Edit:**

It seems to work when I change the `$db->add('status',$status);` line to:

```
$status->user_unavailability_id = $db->id;
$status->save();
```

Not pretty though and still wondering what's preventing me from using the `add` function.

Comment: Its better to use `$status->user_availability = $db`. Also, you dont need to call `$status->save()` before saving `belongs_to` relationship.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. @biakaveron can you help clarify this as it is exactly what I'm confused by. If `Model_A` belongs to `Model_B`, and I do `$a->b = $b;`, I don't need to call `$a->save()` or I don't need to call `$b->save()`?? Or wait, I simply never call save because the assignment (`__set()`) will do the job?

Comment: No, `__set()` will just modify model without saving (https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/ORM.php#L743). Make all changes in $a model and then save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add()` is used in [has_many "through"](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany-through) relationships.

In your case you have already written the correct way:

```
$status->user_unavailability_id = $db->id;
$status->save();
```